# Get data from Twitter using Tweepy and store in csv file

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, twitter, tweepy

I'm new to Python, Twitter, and Tweepy. I managed to pull data from Twitter, but I now want to store it into a CSV file.

My code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import tweepy

auth = tweepy.auth.OAuthHandler('XXXXXX', 'XXXXXXX'
auth.set_access_token('XXX-XXX', 'XXX'

api = tweepy.API(auth)
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
                           q="google",
                           since="2014-02-14",
                           until="2014-02-15",
                           lang="en").items():
    print tweet.created_at, tweet.text
```

This prints data out on CLI, but I want it to output to a CSV file. I tried a few different options, but it only outputted the first tweet and not all tweets.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This will do the job!

I will recommend you to use [csv](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer) from Python. Open a file and write to it during your loop like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import tweepy
import csv #Import csv
auth = tweepy.auth.OAuthHandler('XXXXXX', 'XXXXXXX')
auth.set_access_token('XXX-XXX', 'XXX')

api = tweepy.API(auth)

# Open/create a file to append data to
csvFile = open('result.csv', 'a')

#Use csv writer
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
                           q = "google",
                           since = "2014-02-14",
                           until = "2014-02-15",
                           lang = "en").items():

    # Write a row to the CSV file. I use encode UTF-8
    csvWriter.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode('utf-8')])
    print tweet.created_at, tweet.text
csvFile.close()
```

Comment: Thanks so much this is exactly what I was looking for! The output is not formatted great I would like the Date/Time, Tweet for each line is that possible?

Comment: Great! in the csv you have first the date and time(Y-m-d H:M:S) and then the tweet. you want the date/time in another format ?

Comment: Sorry no the format of the date/time is perfect. When it outputs to CSV it is not seperated by tab or something and is quite messing ideally i'd like the format to be:

Column1,Column2
date/time,tweet

Comment: Ok, you can pass csv writer a delimiter with tab like this: delimiter=' '.
change this line : csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile) to : csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile, delimiter=' ')

Comment: The csv is empty for me.

Comment: Hi...I don't understand the looping very well. Can you explain what's happening in the loop and where my code will go. I'm following this blog :http://adilmoujahid.com/posts/2014/07/twitter-analytics/

Answer (score -2):

You can actually run the program and print the output on another file.
Goto CMD and type

`python file.py > newFile.py`

The output from file.py will be read to newFile.py