# Tweet extraction using Tweepy with specific fields required

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, web-scraping, tweepy

I am trying to extract tweets based on certain hashtags or keywords and want to capture the following information:
date, username (who tweeted), number of retweets, and number of likes.

I want all this information in a column row format and export the same in Excel or CSV format. I have tried the below code, but I am unable to get everything.

How can I do it?

```
import tweepy
import csv
ckey = "*************"
csecret = "******************"
atoken = "****************"
asecret = "************************"
OAUTH_KEYS = {'consumer_key':ckey,'consumer_secret':csecret,'access_token_key':atoken,'access_token_secret':asecret}
auth=tweepy.OAuthHandler(OAUTH_KEYS['consumer_key'],OAUTH_KEYS['consumer_secret'api = tweepy.API(auth)
testTweet = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q="Trump AND H1B").items(1000)
for tweet in testTweet:
    print (tweet.created_at, tweet.text, tweet.lang, tweet.user)
```

Answer (score 5):

Tweepy uses the Twitter API, so you can extract all tweets information with [these fields](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/tweets).

You can modify your code in this way:

```
for tweet in testTweet:
    text     = tweet.text
    language = tweet.lang
    date     = tweet.created_at
    username = tweet.user
    retweets = tweet.retweet_count
    likes    = tweet.favorite_count
```

At the end, if you want store all information in an Excel file, I suggest you to use [xlsxwriter](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/). This package allows you to handle the .xls and .xlsx formats, and it's simple to use.

Otherwise, if you want use CSV, please check [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21865413/get-data-from-twitter-using-tweepy-and-store-in-csv-file).

Comment: Thanks @Giordano- I tried to write it to a csv format but it gave me a blank file.

Comment: Can you please edit your question with also the CSV code?

Comment: @Giordano-     csvFile = open('result.csv', 'w')
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, 
                    q="Mercedes", 
                    since="2016-02-14", 
                    until="2016-12-15", 
                    lang="en").items():

    csvWriter.writerow([tweet.user, tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode("utf-8"),tweet.retweet_count,tweet.favorite_count])
    print (tweet.user, tweet.created_at, tweet.text, tweet.retweet_count, tweet.favorite_count)
csvFile.close()

Comment: About this a couple of notes: You are trying to get 10 months of tweets and I think that Twitter restrictions are blocking you. In for loop, your print statement shows something? I mean, I'm thinking that your csv is empty because there aren't data.

Comment: @Giordano- Even after changing the date range to one month the result is blank

Comment: Twitter restrictions allow you to catch only one week of tweets.. please read Twitter API documentation, and try with this range

Comment: @Giordano- Many thanks..need one more help. Your technical expertise is required again :)

Comment: @Giordano- thanks for the prompt reply...not this one the other one where I am unable to write the type of sentiment against each sentiment

Comment: Ok, so the which one regards writing data in csv file? have you the project on the github page? can you linked it?

Comment: Its a company confidential so I cant link it :(

Comment: Its only the last part where I want to add a positive against a positive sentiment and negative against a negative sentiment , thats what I am trying to achieve

Comment: below is the link:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43779723/text-analysis-unable-to-write-output-of-python-program-in-csv-or-xls-file