# Text analysis-Unable to write output of Python program in csv or xls file

Tags: python, python-2.7, sentiment-analysis, naivebayes, text-analysis

Hi I am trying to do a sentiment analysis using Naive Bayes classifier in python 2.x. It reads the sentiment using a txt file and then gives output as positive or negative based on the sample txt file sentiments.
I want the output the same form as input e.g. I have a text file of lets sat 1000 raw  sentiments and I want the output to show positive or negative against each sentiment.
Please help.
Below is the code i am using

```
import math
import string

def Naive_Bayes_Classifier(positive, negative, total_negative, total_positive, test_string):
    y_values = [0,1]
    prob_values = [None, None]

    for y_value in y_values:
        posterior_prob = 1.0

        for word in test_string.split():
            word = word.lower().translate(None,string.punctuation).strip()
            if y_value == 0:
                if word not in negative:
                    posterior_prob *= 0.0
                else:
                    posterior_prob *= negative[word]
            else:
                if word not in positive:
                    posterior_prob *= 0.0
                else:
                    posterior_prob *= positive[word]

        if y_value == 0:
            prob_values[y_value] = posterior_prob * float(total_negative) / (total_negative + total_positive)
        else:
            prob_values[y_value] = posterior_prob * float(total_positive) / (total_negative + total_positive)

    total_prob_values = 0
    for i in prob_values:
        total_prob_values += i

    for i in range(0,len(prob_values)):
        prob_values[i] = float(prob_values[i]) / total_prob_values

    print prob_values

    if prob_values[0] > prob_values[1]:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sentiment = open(r'C:/Users/documents/sample.txt')

    #Preprocessing of training set
    vocabulary = {}
    positive = {}
    negative = {}
    training_set = []
    TOTAL_WORDS = 0
    total_negative = 0
    total_positive = 0

    for line in sentiment:
        words = line.split()
        y = words[-1].strip()
        y = int(y)

        if y == 0:
            total_negative += 1
        else:
            total_positive += 1

        for word in words:
            word = word.lower().translate(None,string.punctuation).strip()
            if word not in vocabulary and word.isdigit() is False:
                vocabulary[word] = 1
                TOTAL_WORDS += 1
            elif word in vocabulary:
                vocabulary[word] += 1
                TOTAL_WORDS += 1

            #Training
            if y == 0:
                if word not in negative:
                    negative[word] = 1
                else:
                    negative[word] += 1
            else:
                if word not in positive:
                    positive[word] = 1
                else:
                    positive[word] += 1

    for word in vocabulary.keys():
        vocabulary[word] = float(vocabulary[word])/TOTAL_WORDS

    for word in positive.keys():
        positive[word] = float(positive[word])/total_positive

    for word in negative.keys():
        negative[word] = float(negative[word])/total_negative

    test_string = raw_input("Enter the review: \n")

    classifier = Naive_Bayes_Classifier(positive, negative, total_negative, total_positive, test_string)
    if classifier == 0:
        print "Negative review"
    else:
        print "Positive review"
```

Comment: Hi hitesh, based on what I have understand, you want as output a csv/xls file with the words of the sentence that the user insert as input. For each words you want the relative sentiment (positive or negative) calculated by your classifier. Is it correct? Can you please provide an example of the wanted csv/xls file? thank you

Comment: I will paste the contents of the csv file below:

Comment: A good product - your work is simply fun!
Excellent experience with it over many years.
Good product
Good result
I don't use it any more
I has been a stable product
Overall a very good product compared to the rest
Products works fine, but others tell me that some other products are superior.
robust
slow
the best of all
trouble installing
User Friendly
very bad
Very difficult to understand logs and cumbersome to setup and deploy, correctly.

Comment: below is the code which i am running. the commented part is the existing area where the code asks for one sentiment and then assigns it as positive or negative:

Comment: .......contd 
    for word in vocabulary.keys():
        vocabulary[word] = float(vocabulary[word])/TOTAL_WORDS

    for word in positive.keys():
        positive[word] = float(positive[word])/total_positive

    for word in negative.keys():
        negative[word] = float(negative[word])/total_negative
        
#        test_string = raw_input("Enter the review: \n")
#
#    classifier = Naive_Bayes_Classifier(positive, negative, total_negative, total_positive, test_string)
#    if classifier == 0:
#        print "Negative review"
#    else:
#        print "Positive review"

Comment: @Giordano- did you get a chance to see? do let me know

Comment: No i didn't, sorry about that. Can you please edit your question with the additional details added in the comments?

Comment: @Giordano- How will I upload the sample file here? Can i share at your email?

Comment: Yes, if you want you can upload it on github and share the link

Comment: @Giordano- Here it is. Please let me know if you have any doubts.

Comment: https://github.com/hiteshkumarpant/hiteshNB20170623

Answer (score 1):

I've checked the github repo posted by you in comments. I tried to run the project, but I have some errors.

Anyway, I've checked the project structure and the file used to training the naive bayes algorithm, and I think that the following piece of code can be used to write your result data in a Excel file (i.e. .xls)

```
with open("test11.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        classifier = naive_bayes_classifier(positive, negative, total_negative, total_positive, line)
        result = 'Positive' if classifier == 0 else 'Negative'
        data_to_be_written += ([line, result],)

# Create a workbook and add a worksheet.
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xls')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Start from the first cell. Rows and columns are zero indexed.
row = 0
col = 0

# Iterate over the data and write it out row by row.
for item, cost in data_to_be_written:
   worksheet.write(row, col,     item)
worksheet.write(row, col + 1, cost)
row += 1

workbook.close()
```

Sorthly, for each row of the file with the sentences to be tested, I call the classifier and prepare a structure that will be written in the csv file.
Then loop the structure and write the xls file. 
To do this I have used a python site package called xlsxwriter.

As I told you before, I have some problem to run the project, so this code is not tested as well. It should be works well, bu anyway, if you are in trouble, let me know.

Regards

Comment: @Giordano- Thanks.  I tried running but got some errors.

Comment: divide by zero error.  i tried changing the code a bit still the same.

Comment: unfortunately no, i'm sorry

Answer (score 0):

```
> with open("test11.txt") as f:
>     for line in f:
>         classifier = Naive_Bayes_Classifier(positive, negative, total_negative, total_positive, line) if classifier == 0:
>       f.write(line + 'Negative') else:
>        f.write(line + 'Positive')
>     
> #        result = 'Positive' if classifier == 0 else 'Negative'
> #        data_to_be_written += ([line, result],)
> 
> # Create a workbook and add a worksheet. workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xls') worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
> 
> # Start from the first cell. Rows and columns are zero indexed. row = 0 col = 0
> 
> # Iterate over the data and write it out row by row. for item, cost in f:    worksheet.write(row, col,     item) worksheet.write(row, col +
> 1, cost) row += 1
> 
> workbook.close()
```