# Error on getting user id from twitter using tweepy?

Tags: python, python-2.7, twitter, tweepy

my code

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import tweepy
import csv #Import csv
auth = tweepy.auth.OAuthHandler('XXXXXX', 'XXXXXXX')
auth.set_access_token('XXX-XXX', 'XXX')

api = tweepy.API(auth)

# Open/create a file to append data to
csvFile = open('result.csv', 'a')

#Use csv writer
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
                       q = "google",
                       since = "2014-02-14",
                       until = "2014-02-15",
                       lang = "en").items():

# Write a row to the CSV file. I use encode UTF-8
csvWriter.writerow([tweet.created_at,tweet.user, tweet.text.encode('utf-8')])
print tweet.created_at, tweet.text
csvFile.close()
```

Here I am unable to get user_id  in the output.
the output is

> 2018-04-24 10:54:34 RT @BoldContentTV: Very excited to debut our first video for @StylistMagazine and . Featuring the talented @ericafmstyle, #Fashi…

what is the reason? and how can I get the user id? I want three aspects date/userid/text.

I got the code [from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21865413/get-data-from-twitter-using-tweepy-and-store-in-csv-file)

Answer (score 1):

You can get,

username : `tweet.user.screen_name`

text as : `tweet.text`

created_at : `tweet.created_at`

sample code:

```
In [33]: import tweepy

In [34]: auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler('', '')

In [35]: auth.set_access_token('', '')

In [36]: api = tweepy.API(auth)

In [37]: for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q = "nishant").items(5):
    ...:     print tweet.user.screen_name , tweet.text, tweet.created_at
    ...:

GuruInAJeans RT @periferrydotcom: Shaina's story is all about courage and the will to achieve.
it shows how patience can go a long way.

Full Story: htt… 2018-04-24 13:02:42
bajjiladeva @ts_nishant @KTRTRS neku ikkada first nene chepta bro inauguration date .. 2018-04-24 12:57:37
ts_nishant Don’t @KTRTRS <twitter short url> 2018-04-24 12:55:43
ts_nishant When @KTRTRS ?? <twitter short url> 2018-04-24 12:55:13
parivesh100 Nishant Shah on the invisible environmental costs that the digital age has brought - <twitter short url> 2018-04-24 12:47:56
```